# Dynamically customize django admin columns?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

Is it possible to let the users choose / change dynamically the columns displayed in a object list in Django administration ?

Things can surely be implemented "from scratch" by modifying the 'change_list.html' template but I was wondering if somebody has already had the same problem and/or if any django-pluggin can do that.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Since Django 1.4 you can do this using get_list_display(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display

Answer (score 3):

[django-xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin) has this feature:

[image: django x-admin dynamic columns]

It has some other cool features too, but I haven't started using it because the English translation of the documentation hasn't been released yet (as of Oct '13). You could look at the source code to give you some ideas.

Check out the [live demo](http://demo.xadmin.io)

User: admin
Password: admin

Note: I have no involvement in x-admin, I just have the same question as the OP.

Comment: I tried to use x-admin with python3 and it's basically broken. I fix a problem with reload (reloading a module smells bad code btw) and another issue pops-up.

Comment: is there a replacement for this now?

Answer (score 0):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, the solution is to set list_display in your extension of ModelAdmin for that object.  Refer to the [Django Tutorial, Part 2](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-change-list).

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. In fact, my question was : how can a application user (not a developer) change ** dynamically** the displayed column (from the admin interface, not from the python code). I don't know if it is possible...

Comment: thanks for your clarification.  If I had to guess, I'd assume the simplest route would be to edit the templates and add a massive amount of CSS to hide/un-hide certain columns and insert a menu to toggle it, but this is a fairly uneducated guess and pretty far from ideal.

Comment: Matt, that's hard to do since Django doesn't mark up change list columns e.g. with the field name as a CSS class. That's what http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/11195/ aims to fix.