# Dynamically customize django admin columns in model view

Tags: django

Follow up to this quetsion:
[Dynamically customize django admin columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600972/dynamically-customize-django-admin-columns)

How to do it with django 4.2

lib django-xadmin doesnt work with django 4.2

This model for example

```
`class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='choice')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)`
```

and admin page

```
`class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['question_text', 'pub_date', 'choice_text', 'votes']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)`
```